# Remove question mark at the end of the query in AFNetworking 3 GET request

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

I have request URL like this:

```
https://myserver.com/api/news/?offset=0?
```

In parameters dict I pass it like this:

> @{ @"offset" : @(0)}

Why question mark at the end of my request appears, and how can I get rid of it?

After request I logging it's full info like this:

```
  NSLog(@"%@ | URL - %@?%@", sessionDataTaskGETReq.originalRequest.HTTPMethod,
                  sessionDataTaskGETReq.originalRequest.URL,
                  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:sessionDataTaskGETReq.originalRequest.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

And here I see this additional question mark at the end.

My request and response serializers looks like this:

```
  AFJSONRequestSerializer *requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [requestSerializer setValue:@"application/json, multipart/form-data, @text/html" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

    AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer
                                                       serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];;
    responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithArray:@[@"multipart/form-data", @"text/html", @"text/json", @"application/json"]];
```

Comment: Are you talking about a question mark on XCode? If that's the case, provide us with any additional info you're getting.

Comment: @Orlando,what do you mean "in Xcode?" I updated my question

Comment: @Orlando, yes. server server receiving this question mark

Comment: It's not a big problem for your server, it shouldn't cause any kind of errors.

Comment: @dalejin Fine, I deleted by accident my previous comment (while trying to edit it). I saw you replied. Sorry about it. You're putting the params in the request body, right? How does your AFNetworking `AFHTTPSessionManager`'s `requestSerializer` and `responseSerializer` look like?

Comment: @Orlando added this in question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSLog(@"%@ | URL - %@%@", sessionDataTaskGETReq.originalRequest.HTTPMethod,
                  sessionDataTaskGETReq.originalRequest.URL,
                  [[NSString alloc] initWithData:sessionDataTaskGETReq.originalRequest.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

just remove your question mark you added in NSLog

Comment: @dalejin are you sure the server is receiving the question mark as you said?

Comment: you say the url like this : https://myserver.com/api/news/?offset=0? 

then it already have a question mark , or , you can print the result from NSLog to see the exact problem

the correct url must be 

https://myserver.com/api/news/?offset=0 

or 
https://myserver.com/api/news/?offset=0& 
if have more attribute

Comment: @Orlando oh... I'm stupid, there is no any "?" at the end of query. It was only in NSLog

Comment: @daleijn happens all the time with NSLog for debugging! Then I think Bassam got your answer, right?